# postgresql ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table in JAVA query execution

Tags: java, postgresql

i read the same kind issue here, everywhere there is some problems with query.

I facing this error `ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table` in query, which is executing if i execute it manually, not in JAVA back-end code.

this is manual query, which is works well when i execute it in DBMS:

```
INSERT INTO goods (condo_id, item_title, item_descr, item_email, item_phone, item_price)
VALUES (3, 'Title', 'bfDEscr', 'grergeg@mail.com', '54654654654', '4545');
```

and this is statement in JAVA:

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("INSERT INTO goods (condo_id, item_title, item_descr, item_email, item_phone, item_price) VALUES\n" +
                "(item.condo_id, item.title, item.descr, item.email, item.phone, item.price);");
```

which is doesn't work and on which after execution i got exception with error.

This is Item class. I checked, in JAVA back-end, all values is received well and existed.

```
public class Item {
    public int condo_id;
    public String title;
    public String descr;
    public String phone;
    public String email;
    public int price;
    }
```

Comment: t am not really sure about queries from Java, but I guess you should not add a `;` at the end of the query when sending through java...(Just my guess).

Comment: Your Java example lists *column names* in `VALUES` clause. You need to put real values in there. Even better: use a `PreparedStatement`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE queries you should use `Statement.executeUpdate`, for SELECT - `Statement.executeQuery`, javadoc clearly states it.

Answer (score 1):

1. your query in the java code contains some unwanted characters such as `\n` and `;`
2. you are not passing any parameter
3. I would suggest you to use `prepared statement` to avoid injection

sample based on your code:

```
Connection con = ...;
PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO goods (condo_id, item_title, item_descr, item_email, item_phone, item_price) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
statement.setLong(1, item.condo_id );
statement.setString(2, item.item_title);
statement.setsetString(3, item.item_descr );
//...all other missing bindings
statement.execute();
```

of course you need to have an instance to `item` to retrieve the values. I suggest as best practice to define as `private` the fields in your Item class and access them using getters/setters

Comment: `\n` is not a problem in a SQL string.

Comment: there is no need to have a `\n` in the query at all even if it is not harmful

Comment: `;` unwanted? is it not just the end of query?

yes, sure, i got the instance of Item to retrieve the values. all values passed to query successfully, checked that.

Why is getters/setters usage is better? just making a code more complicated, no?

Comment: by the way, using this 
          `int rowsUpdated = st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO goods (condo_id, item_title, item_descr, item_email, item_phone, item_price) VALUES\n" +
                    "(item.condo_id, item.title, item.descr, item.email, item.phone, item.price);");`

still getting the same error(

Comment: `;` is not needed using `JDBC`. You are still using a string instead of parameters: `"(item.condo_id, item.title, item.descr, item.email, item.phone, item.price);"` see my code snippet above or this working [example](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-insert-a-record/) even if in that example the connection is to an Oracle db the insert behavior is the same. more complete examples [here](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/jdbc-tutorials/)